# TmxMapLoader null point exception with infinite area tmx file

Tags: libgdx

I used tiled to create a tilemap, and this map has infinite area.
The resulted tmx file has bunch of 0s, and this is causing nullpointerexeception for getTileIds.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.BaseTmxMapLoader.getTileIds(BaseTmxMapLoader.java:298)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.BaseTmxMapLoader.loadTileLayer(BaseTmxMapLoader.java:81)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.loadTilemap(TmxMapLoader.java:203)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:90)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
at com.pokemon.TiledGameMap.<init>(TiledGameMap.java:17)
at com.pokemon.PlatformerGame.create(PlatformerGame.java:23)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

What can I do to skip 0s in tmx file? I haven't placed any tiles here, as not needed.

EDIT:  I created a 32 x 32 tilemap with filled tiles, and this works fine. So I'm pretty sure nullpointer comes from not filled tiles. I want to bypass this, as my map has weird shape.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Do you have the "Infinite" box checked? I had this same issue, and was able to get around it by unchecking the box, then saving my map.